# Controlling phone functions with HTML

Tags: html

Can I can control my phone functions with HTML?

For example:

```
<a href="tel:+1800229933">Some Service</a>
```

will call that number. Now I wonder whether I can add this number to my contacts book, with the name field populated as "Some Service". Where can I get TEL: and similar clickable link methods?

**Note:**
Original source of question is [here](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/291675-controlling-phone-functions-html-contacts-list.html).

Comment: Programming questions should be in StackOverflow.com :)

Comment: Be aware, that there's a [USSDFIX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.ussdfix&hl=en) that will protect from this sort of thing (You have heard about the USSD exploit used by Samsung that a html link pointing to a url that contains tel: can remotely wipe/factory reset upon browsing a page?)